# What for we need to check this condition Float.isNaN(loadFactor) in HashMap constructor ?

Tags: java, collections, constructor, hashmap

```
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " +
                                           initialCapacity);
    if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
    if (loadFactor <= 0 || **Float.isNaN(loadFactor)**)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal load factor: " +
                                           loadFactor);

    this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    threshold = initialCapacity;
    init();
}
```

Do not we get a compilation error immediately when will create the new HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) if loadFactor is not number?

p.s. Sorry for my English)

Comment: No, it's a runtime exception. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Try `Map map = new HashMap(10, (float)(0.0/0));` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, i got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal load factor: NaN

Answer (score 0):

Error checks at compilation time don't come for free; somebody has to implement it. It so happens that this particular check was not implemented in the compiler as it wasn't deemed worth it.

Note also that while in some situations this error could (in theory) be detected at compile time, in many situations it won't be possible to detect this error. For example, if the number is given by the user at runtime, there is no way the compiler can detect that.